# Can't install mysql2 Gem on MAMP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mamp, mysql2

After running bundle install, I got this error. I've tried editing the  /etc/paths file and it still hasn't worked.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150224-4249-ltvvu1.rb extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... no
-----
errmsg.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

#### Gemfile

```
ruby-2.1.5
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
gem 'mysql2'
```

#### /etc/paths

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Is this related to my MySql installation?

Comment: This definitely has an answer somewhere already. I know because I used it when I was setting this up on my machine. However, the fact that I can't find it anymore means it clearly isn't as canonical as it should be.

Comment: @Jon - I've looked and tried different solutions to this and it has been a different case-to-case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this by simply running gem install using the mysql config an existing config.

```
gem install mysql2 -v {mysql2_gem_version} --  --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/{mysql_gem_version}/bin/mysql_config



gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

First add the below dependencies by using below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5

sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client
```

Finally Add gem `'mysql2', '~> 0.3.16'` in Gemfile and bundle install

Comment: Hi @VDN    I'm using OSX.   apt-get is work linux, will use homebrew for the dependencies. Thanks! I'll update you if it works.

Comment: I did this.    gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.10/bin/mysql_config       And it actually worked

Comment: This bug was recurring again in production deployment. zzzz

Comment: Not useful using macOS

Answer (score -2):

Off topic:

I experienced this problem when I deployed my app to production (Linux Server)

I had to install this to fix the missing gem

yum install mysql-devel

Comment: Not useful using macOS.